# centering divs in ie

Tags: html, css

My divs do not center properly in IE, it works fine in Firefox.

I've tried following this site: http://flumpcakes.co.uk/css/center-div-ie but the container div appears in the right hand side in IE.

```
<div id="topbar">
  <div id="previous"> &#171; {block:PreviousPage} {/block:PreviousPage} </div>
  <div id="next"> {block:NextPage} {/block:NextPage} &#187; </div>
</div>

<div id="container">

  <div id="header">

    <div id="logo">
      Title here please
    </div>

    <div id="tagline">
      So, why do arrays start from zero?
    </div>

    <div id="topmenu" class="toplinks">
      Home <a href="/archive">Archive</a> Ask Me Archive Random
    </div>

    <div id="search">
      <form action="/search" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="q" value="" id="" />
      </form>
    </div>   


  </div>


  <div id="posts-container">

    <div id="posts">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, post content goes here
    </div>

    <div id="leftmenu">
      <div id="date" >
        23rd November 2010
      </div>

      <div id="posttitle">
        This is a title and it contains all that you may need...
      </div>
      <i>- Filed under Misc -<i>

    </div>

  </div>



</div>
```

The css:

```
body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family:Georgia,"Times New Roman",Serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align:center;
}


#topbar
{
    height: 25px;
    background: #030303;
    min-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
}

#container
{
    width: 800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

#header
{
    height: 140px;
    width: 800px;
}

#logo
{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 45px;
    position: absolute;
}

#tagline
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin-top: 89px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
}

#topmenu
{
    margin-top: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 500px;
}

#search
{
    margin-top: 62px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 570px; 
    float: right;
}


#next
{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    width: 350px;
    padding:3px;
    float: right;
}

#previous
{
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    width: 350px;
    padding:3px;
    float: left; 
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px; 
}

#posts-container
{
    width: 800px;
    text-align: center;
}

#posts
{
    width: 613px;
    margin-left:177px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 3px;
    text-align: left;

}

#leftmenu
{
    width:175px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

#posttitle
{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#date
{
    background: #d4ff40;
    width: 165px;
    height: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #7c9c2d;
    margin: 5 auto;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just delete `text-align:center;` from `body`, `#container` and `#posts-container`

Answer (score 0):

> My divs do not center properly in IE, it works fine in Firefox

I'm not going to try to parse that HTML and CSS in my head (working links are appreciated) but odds are that you are in Quirks mode.

Add a [Doctype that triggers standards mode](http://gutfeldt.ch/matthias/articles/doctypeswitch/table.html).

Comment: I'm using <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">

Comment: Which is listed as triggering Quirks mode. HTML 4.0 became a recommendation in 1997. It is time to leave HTML 3.2 behind. HTML 4.01 is the latest version of HTML to reach Recommendation level. `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Comment: If HTML Tidy stuck an HTML 3.2 Doctype on it, then it is probably because the document looked more like HTML 3.2 then HTML 4.01.